# Fast Java binary format parsing

Tags: java, performance, parsing, binary

I regularly deal with different binary file formats in our Java EE application suite, i.e. reading into some class structure and writing them back. I need to have operations like:

- read single byte / short / int / long, sometimes different endianness (little/big)
- read single bits in flags, i.e.

  ```
  | uint16_t | 4 bits | 4 bits | uint16_t |
  ```

  should become something like

  ```
  a = stream.readUint16();
  byte tmp = stream.readUint8();
  b = (tmp & 0xf0) >> 4;
  c = (tmp & 0xf)
  d = stream.readUint16();
  ```
- read strings in different encodings, sometimes dynamic length strings with something like a `\0` ending
- seeking in a file (to find data dictated by some offsets read), knowing current position, knowing how much have I left to parse in current data block
- last, but not least, it should be fast; at least not an order of magnitude slower than declaring a `typedef struct` in C, reading it as a block and typecasting it in memory

So far I've analyzed my options and found that there are:

- `RandomAccessFile` — best one in standard Java, has proper seeking and position methods, string read, etc, but sometimes unbearably slow due to lack of buffering in operations like ; also no bit-level access to the stream and no different endianness support
- `FileInputStream` — can only read individual bytes, one has to reconstruct primitive datatypes by hand; no seeking
- `*Reader` interaces — basically, can only read bytes and array of bytes, can skip, mark and reset, but they tend to leak memory if seeking is done multiple times as `reset(); skip(seekAmount);`
- https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser — almost exactly what I'm looking for — i.e. a declarative specification of a format and then, voila, I've got classes, but it's essentially an interpreter, thus there are 2 major problems: (a) it's slow in high-demanding environments, (b) there are multiple type safety problems with runtime-generated reflection-like style
- http://preon.codehaus.org/ — has lots of great reviews, but seems to be no longer developed, site is down :(

I've searched Google, I've searched StackOverflow. This question —
[How to parse/encode binary message formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862855/how-to-parse-encode-binary-message-formats) — addresses the same issue, but with weird non-aligned bits requirement which I don't have.

So, questions is — am I overlooking something and there are any better solutions for this problem that address *all* what I've mentioned?

Comment: [Preon](https://github.com/preon/preon) is alive and kicking, it's just not anymore at the Codehaus. However, I don't think that it would be a lot of help for you, given that you're *not* dealing with unaligned structures.

Answer (score 7):

[ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) has everything you need.
It's also probably the fastest option in pure Java (not counting JNI, sun.misc.Unsafe etc.)

- [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get--), [`getShort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getShort--), [`getInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt--) etc. to read all primitive types and byte arrays;
- [`order`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order-java.nio.ByteOrder-) to switch between BIG_ENDIAN and LITTLE_ENDIAN;
- [`position`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position-int-) for seeking;
- [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html), [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) can encode/decode strings directly in ByteBuffer;
- [`FileChannel.map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map-java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode-long-long-) creates a ByteBuffer mapped to a file;
- there are two kinds of ByteBuffers for data in Java heap and off heap.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to suggest this as a solution, but given that you seem to have some knowledge of how to do this in C, you could construct a library of appropriate functions in C then wrap that with JNI and use that in your application.

Perhaps this is just one of those rare occasions where "going native" is appropriate for your use case?